# Cassandra - best practice for node size

Tags: cassandra

Is there a best practice for node sizes?

We are currently running a 3 node cluster, RF=3.
Our loads:

```
Datacenter: datacenter-prod
===========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                              Rack
UN  10.164.0.23   7.55 GiB   256          100.0%            e7e2a38a-d4f3-4758-a345-73fcffe26035  rack1
UN  10.164.0.24   7.61 GiB   256          100.0%            0c18b8e4-5ca2-4fb5-9e8c-663b74909fbb  rack1
UN  10.164.0.58   7.61 GiB   256          100.0%            547c0746-72a8-4fec-812a-8b926d2426ae  rack1
```

The nodes are running cassandra only. The disk usage is as follows:

```
root@cassandra-1:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          99G   20G   75G  22% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1        99G   20G   75G  22% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /sys/firmware
```

So each node has used ~ 20G out of 100G assigned.

- What should we do when we go towards to 100Gb mark?
- Should we add more disk space or add more nodes?

I remember that its better to have small nodes in case of crashes / recovery operations.

- How many nodes and with which RF do we need to add then in order to rebalance the disk usages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a straightforward rule, but 1 TB in data size, is usually a good sweet spot. This data size goes well with at least 16 GB (or 32 GB of memory to stay on the safe side), and most importantly, use SSDs (not spinning disks).

Keep in mind that if you want to stick with best practices, that for 1 TB of data load, you should have 2 TB in of total disk size, due to compactions.

Comment: Does it make sense to use smaller disk sizes so the nodes can use less ram? Is there a rule-of-thumb how much RAM a node with x GB of data should have?

Comment: There's no rule for that because it depends a lot of things, e.g. your data model. For instance, if you have LCS in a table with lots of data, you will need to have a bigger amount of RAM to accommodate all the SSTables from LCS, which usually has more than STCS.